# how to Reload property placeholder manually in spring without refreshing entire application context

Tags: java, spring

I am using property placeholder configuration with DatabaseConfiguration. I want to reload property placeholder bean alone without refreshing entire application context. I'll call Rest url to reload placeholder manually not automatic reloading. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the property placeholder does. Refreshing it won't help you if the values are read at startup by singletons.

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I know what property placeholder does, well it is singleton will load at startup event, but there are ways to reload spring beans dynamically based on event based, For eg: We can reload property placeholder based on file modified date, but that above solution won't work out as I am using Database configuration and need to load manually.

Comment: And then. You have reloaded your properties, how are the beans using those properties will be refreshed? The only way to do that is to rebuild the whole (or a large part) of your context. You might want to take a look at what was build for the Spring Cloud Config project with a `@RefreshScope` specially for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum "You have reloaded your properties, how are the beans using those properties will be refreshed?" That's exactly what I asked earlier ("Refreshing it won't help you if the values are read at startup by singletons."), to which he gave an answer that made no sense to me.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is that am not using spring boot application, there are other ways to reload spring bean..Refer to this link https://github.com/jamesmorgan/ReloadablePropertiesAnnotation . He gave the solution for file reloading, I am searching the same for database configuration.

Comment: As stated by multiple comments, just reloading the properties gives you nothing. You need to refresh your beans. I also nowhere stated you should use that project I said you should look at it for inspiration ...